# How to fix Augeas dependency for Tomcat manifest?

Tags: tomcat, debian, puppet, augeas

I've the following puppet manifest which suppose to install and run Tomcat on port 8983:

```
# tomcat.pp
package { [ "tomcat7", "tomcat7-admin" ]: ensure => present }
package { [ "augeas-tools", "libaugeas-dev", "libaugeas-ruby" ]: ensure => installed }

class { 'java': }
class { 'tomcat': install_from_source => false }

tomcat::config::server { 'tomcat7':
  catalina_base => '/etc/tomcat7/Catalina',
  port          => '8983',
  require => [ Package["libaugeas-ruby"] ]
}->
tomcat::service { 'default':
  use_jsvc     => false,
  use_init     => true,
  service_name => 'tomcat7',
}
```

I've installed all dependencies, e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install puppet augeas-tools libaugeas-dev libaugeas-ruby
sudo puppet module install puppetlabs/tomcat
```

Here is my puppet and augeas packages:

```
$ puppet --version
2.7.23

$ dpkg -l | grep augeas
ii  augeas-lenses                       0.10.0-1 
ii  augeas-tools                        0.10.0-1 
ii  libaugeas-dev                       0.10.0-1 
ii  libaugeas-ruby                      0.4.1-1.1
ii  libaugeas-ruby1.8                   0.4.1-1.1
ii  libaugeas-ruby1.9.1                 0.4.1-1.1
ii  libaugeas0                          0.10.0-1
```

However when I run my manifest, it's saying that I don't have Augeas installed:

```
$ sudo puppet apply -v tomcat-test.pp 
Server configurations require Augeas >= 1.0.0 at /etc/puppet/modules/tomcat/manifests/config/server.pp:28 on node debian-wheezy
```

I've read [Using Puppet with Augeas](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/puppet_augeas) and `augtool` tool works correctly.

How do I fix that broken dependency? Or do I need to restart anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This manifest requires Augeas >= 1.0.0, and you have 0.10.0.

You need to upgrade your Augeas package in order to use this.

If you're on Ubuntu, see  [the Augeas PPA](https://launchpad.net/~raphink/+archive/ubuntu/augeas)

On Debian, you can check [Camptocamp's repository](http://pkg.camptocamp.net/).

Answer (score 0):

**Debian/Ubuntu**

Based on [ℝaphink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370796/55075) suggestion, I've added the Camptocamp package repository as below:

```
$ echo 'deb     http://pkg.camptocamp.net/apt wheezy/stable sysadmin' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ curl -s http://pkg.camptocamp.net/packages-c2c-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
OK
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-cache madison "augeas*" | grep camptocamp
libaugeas-ruby1.8 | 0.5.0-0c2c1 | http://pkg.camptocamp.net/apt/ wheezy/stable/sysadmin amd64 Packages
augeas-tools | 1.3.0-0+c2c1 | http://pkg.camptocamp.net/apt/ wheezy/stable/sysadmin amd64 Packages
```

And installed it via `apt`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install augeas-tools=1.\* augeas-lenses=1.\* augeas-doc=1.\* libaugeas0=1.\*
$ dpkg -l '*augeas*'
ii augeas-tools  1.3.0-0+c2c1
ii libaugeas0  1.3.0-0+c2c1
```

And it works now.